# react native 403 permission error from php api on wamp server

Tags: php, react-native, http-status-code-403

[react native error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN8Db.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  async getMovies() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.6:80/p4Lite/Sept2021/react_backend/index.php');
      const json = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data: json });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.name}, {item.email}</Text>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Above is my app.js file code. It works fine on web but shows error on my android phone using expo go. I have tried various methods but till now is solution fond. I am working on localhost.

Comment: Can you post any error logs that you are getting?

Comment: Please click ( react native error) to view the error shoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your API related folder

```
sudo chmod -R -f 777 /path/to/your/file/or/directory
```

Comment: Thanyou got the general idea of the issue by your answer

Comment: Please accept and vote the answer if it's helpful :) @SilverMoon

Answer (score 0):

the 403 error means that the request you made was forbidden. it is generally received when a required password is not entered.

Most likely, your API requires a password, and this was not provided by the code, the server code is miss-configured, or the server does not have the right permissions to display the result.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Answer (score 0):

Some how it's working by changing:
Require local to Require all granted in httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).